# JSlider not showing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jslider

I am attempting to write a slider that changes the value of a number in a box.

I am trying to set the slider's y location to 0 and set the size of the slider to 200px wide and 30px high.

I have already initialized the the slider instance, and the code for the numbered box is written correctly:

```
 NumberSlider ns = new NumberSlider(controller, "number", 0, 10, 5);
 ns.setSize(200, 100);
 ns.setLocation(400, 200);
 window.add(ns);
```

When placing this in my view class I get the box with a number 5 in it.

So now that I have the box, how can I use the JSlider so that it interacts with the numbered box?

Here is the full constructor:

```
 public NumberSlider(Controller c, String s, int min, int max,int ini_val){

 setLayout(null);
 slider_name = s;
 controller = c;
 Box box = new Box();
 box.setLocation(min, max);
 box.setSize(40, 30);
 String text = String.valueOf(ini_val);
 box.setText(text);
 add(box);

 JSlider jslider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, min, max, ini_val);
```

Comment: It looks like `NumberSlider` inherits from some component. What is the declaration of `NumberSlider`? What is `JSlider jslider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, min, max, ini_val);`? By the way, is there a reason you don't want to use JSpinner which provides very similar functionality? And is there some specific problem you are having?

Comment: package gui;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;

import controller.Controller;

public class NumberSlider extends JPanel {

private String slider_name; 
private Controller controller;
private Box box;
private JSlider jslider;


 
public NumberSlider(Controller c, String s, int min, int max,int ini_val){
 
  setLayout(null);
  slider_name = s;
  controller = c;
  Box box = new Box();
  box.setLocation(min, max);
  box.setSize(40, 30);
  String text = String.valueOf(ini_val);
  box.setText(text);
  add(box); 
}

Comment: this is the entire class minus the initializing  of the jslider instance

Comment: Consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Do you ever add the slider to anything...